# How to return file after storing it at specific path [Laravel]

Tags: php, ajax, file, laravel

Ok, I could receive my file using this line → **$file = Input::file('file');**

and storing it at path using this:

**return $file->move(__DIR__.'/storage/',$file->getClientOriginalName());**

Now, if i need to return this file to user, How ??

Comment: You want to return the path or what exactly are you looking to return?

Comment: no I want to return file itself not path

Comment: you are already returning the moved file.

Comment: this line >> return $file->move(__DIR__.'/storage/',$file->getClientOriginalName());  is just save it to the path but not return it to user

Comment: $file = Input::file('file')->move($destination_path, $destination_filename);return $file;  that is how I do it.. but that returns the file object.  you just skipped a step by doing it in one line.

Comment: I think this line just get the file and save it to [$destination_path],,

and what i need is to return this file when user request it later .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a response wrapper that will set the headers for the response as well as utilising `File::get()` internally. This is for when you just want to grab a file and return it for download without any interim processing on the file.

```
return Response::download($pathToFile);
```

You can set extra data by passing in further params

```
return Response::download($pathToFile, $name, $headers);
```

This uses Symfony HttpFoundation components and as such the file must have an ASCII filename.

[Laravel responses docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses)

Answer (score 0):

[You need to use the `File::get()` function](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#files)

```
return File::get(__DIR__.'/storage/',$file->getClientOriginalName());
```